# Hatcher 2.2.26 Show that if $A$ is contractible in $X$ then $H_n(X,A) \approx \tilde H_n(X) \oplus \tilde H_{n-1}(A)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Show that if $A$ is contractible in $X$ then $H_n(X,A) \approx \tilde H_n(X) \oplus \tilde H_{n-1}(A)$

I know that $\tilde H_n(X \cup CA) \approx H_n(X \cup CA, CA) \approx H_n(X,A)$.

And $(X \cup CA)/X = SA$, where $SA$ is the suspension of $A$. So
$H_n((X \cup CA)/X) = H_n(SA)$, where $SA$ is the suspension of $A$. But $SA \simeq A$, and homology is homotopic invariant, we have $H_n((X \cup CA)/X) = H_n(A)$.

The direct sum points me to Mayer-Vietoris sequence, and I guess I shall write as the direct sum of $X$ and $A$, or the homotopy equivalence respectively. But I am not sure how to meet the homology $H_{n-1}$ on the right hand side of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the long exact sequence of a pair for $n \ge 2$,
$$
H_n(A) \overset{0}{\to} H_n(X) \to H_n(X, A) \to H_{n-1}(A) \overset{0}{\to} H_{n-1}(X),
$$
but one has to work a bit harder for the splitting.

Comment: In fact, the only place that splitting needs to be shown is the case $n=1$ because $H_{n-1}(A)=0$ for all $n\geq 2$ by contractibility of $A$ - hence $\tilde{H}_{n-1}(A)=0$ for all $n\geq 2$. When $n=1$, $H_{n-1}(A)$ is non-trivial.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the induced map $H_*(A)\to H_*(X)$ is always zero though.

Comment: Because $A$ is contractable, so $H_*(A)$ is always zero map, I guess @DanielRust. But I still can't reconcile the question...?

Comment: When for $n=1$, we have $H_0(A)\to H_0(X)$ is a non-zero injection.

Comment: You're right, @DanielRust.  The last map is nonzero when $n = 1$.

Comment: @DanielRust Is it also true that $H_*(A)=0$ when $A$ is contractable in $X$? This seems like a weaker condition than saying it is contractable.

Comment: @Kaladin Looking back at my comments, I have no idea why I assumed $A$ was contractible. Regardless, there was a duplicate question that received a good answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182623/).

Comment: Oke, thank you very much.